# How to upgrade PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.1 on CentOS 7.2 Linode server

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, centos7, php-7.1

I have a `Laravel 5.4` project running on `PHP 7.0.2` on a Linode server with `CentOS 7.2` operating system.

Recently, I upgraded `Laravel 5.4` to `Laravel 5.7`, which required `PHP 7.1.3` or greater.

I have other projects that will NOT work on `PHP 7.2` so I would like to upgrade to `PHP 7.1.3`.

Can anybody help me upgrade?

Comment: Check this out and see if it works for you https://www.ryadel.com/en/php-7-downgrade-rollback-linux-centos-fastcgi-count-countable/

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, php 7.0 is already there on my server. I need to upgrade to PHP 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrading mod_php with Apache

Start by removing existing PHP package

```
$ sudo yum remove php-cli mod_php php-common
```

Install the new PHP 7 packages from IUS.

```
$ sudo yum install mod_php70u php70u-cli php70u-mysqlnd
```

Finally, restart Apache to load the new version of mod_php

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

### Upgrading PHP-FPM with Nginx

Start by removing existing PHP packages.

```
$ sudo yum remove php-fpm php-cli php-common
```

Install the PHP 7 packages from IUS.

```
$ sudo yum install php71u-fpm-nginx php71u-cli php71u-mysqlnd
```

Restart PHP-FPM and Nginx

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

For more info, please see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7

Comment: I am sorry I am using Apache, not Nginx. Let me update my question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Alright, please mark correct if all goes fine. Otherwise, let me know if you need any further assistance.